# Matplotlib : No module named packaging.version

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I got an error when importing matplotlib :

```
File "C:\Users\barre\PycharmProjects\dogs_cats\main.py", line 23, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "C:\Users\barre\PycharmProjects\dogs_cats\venv\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\__init__.py",
line 105, in <module>
from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging.version'
```

Seems that the problem comes from this line from the `__init__.py` file of matplotlib :

> `line 105 : from packaging.version import parse as parse_version`

I tried reinstalling matplotlib with following commands but still the same error :

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install matplotlib
```

Thanks in advance.

My code :

```
import zipfile
import os
import cv2
import time
import random
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

import torchvision.transforms as T
from torchvision.utils import make_grid
from torchvision.models import resnet50

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from PIL import Image

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with zipfile.ZipFile("C:/Users/barre/PycharmProjects/dogs_cats/dogs-vs-cats/train.zip", "r") as z:
    z.extractall(".")

with zipfile.ZipFile("C:/Users/barre/PycharmProjects/dogs_cats/dogs-vs-cats/test1.zip", "r") as z:
    z.extractall(".")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the `packaging` module by running:

```bash
pip install packaging
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I also tried that and still same error, i tried uninstalling and reinstalling packaging but still the same

Comment: Please check the packaging version you installed. You should install the exact version as per the requirements of yours. I too got the same issue for packaging. I then verified that i installed higher version and my requirements was a lower version of packaging so again i reinstalled packaging.